# Ms-Word Labeling through c#.net optimization issue

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, label, office-interop

Currently I am working on the .net desktop application which uses the Ms - Word Labeling functionality.I need to print approximate 5000 records at a time. It takes approximately 3.5 minutes according to my code. Here, in my code I am passing little dummy data but in real scenario I need to pass large data.

My code is:

```
        oWord = new Word.Application();
        oWord.Visible = false;

        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object isVisible = false;
        object filename = @"C:\Users\jc\Desktop\label1.docx";
        object saveFile;

        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(ref filename, ConfirmConversions: false, ReadOnly: true);

        var innerTable = oDoc.Content.Tables[1];

        int totalLabelsPerPage = innerTable.Rows.Count * innerTable.Columns.Count;
        int totalRowsPerPage = innerTable.Rows.Count;
        int totalColumnsPerPage = innerTable.Columns.Count;

        String[] collection = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63" };

        object StartPoint = 0;

        Range MyRange;
        int requiredTables = 1;

        while ((requiredTables * totalRowsPerPage * totalColumnsPerPage) < collection.Length)
        {
            MyRange = oDoc.Range(ref StartPoint, ref missing);
            MyRange.Collapse(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd‌);
            MyRange.InsertBreak(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage);
            MyRange.InsertFile(@"C:\Users\jc\Desktop\label.docx");
            requiredTables++;
        }

        int count = oDoc.Content.Tables.Count;

        int no = 1;
        int columnCount = innerTable.Columns.Count;
        int currentColumn = 1;
        int cont = 0;
        int columns = 1;
        int currentTableNo = 1;

        while (cont <= collection.Length)
        {
            innerTable = oDoc.Content.Tables[currentTableNo];
            innerTable.Range.Bold = 1;
            innerTable.Range.Bold = 1;
            innerTable.Range.Text = "sdadad";
            innerTable.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
            innerTable.Range.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorBlue;
            innerTable.Range.Font.Size = 15F;
            innerTable.Range.Font.Name = "Verdana";
            while (columns <= columnCount)
            {
                innerTable.Columns[columns].Cells[no].Range.Text = collection[cont];
                no++;
                cont++;
                if (cont == collection.Length)
                    break;
                else if (no == totalRowsPerPage+1)
                {
                    columns++;
                    no=1;
                }
            }
            if (cont == collection.Length)
                break;
            else
            {
                columns = 1;
                currentTableNo++;
            }
        }
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        oWord.Visible = true;
        oDoc.Activate();
```

Any help could be greatly appriciated..!!

Thank you!!!

Comment: the only problem is efficiency (time spent)?

Comment: @KazJaw: Yes the only problem is time...

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of your code it, that it uses Interop. Interop is inherently slow as hell - you might speed it up, but it WILL still take ages.
At best, you could create your file without Word, with a library or Office open xml directly which can create a .docx file without opening word.
The downside is, that this consumes a lot more development resources than your simple code mentioned above.
So you have to decide if its worth the development time.
Maybe this would help:http://docx.codeplex.com/ I don't know the library, but ANY library is preferable to dealing with Office Open XML directly.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion..and I will try to implement but actually I don't want to increase my installation package size. So I was initially not preferring 3rd party dll.

Comment: Most of the Office Open XMl packages I have seen are very lightweight, I thinkt that wil be the case for .docx libraries. 
Why is the filesize an issue for you?

Comment: We are providing so many functionalities in our application.So already its bulky and now we are giving setups to our clients by internet. So we would like that our client can get the setup within 5 minutes..

Comment: I can honsetly understand that - but I think the hassle of Word interop (what if the client HAS no Word installation, or a future version which behaves differently or is doing critical work in Word which isses an checkbox which blocks your app?) far outweighs download constraints.
I am developing a rather large Powerpoint interop application and a Office Open XMl solution for different clients and would take the Office Open XMl route again - it is harder to learn, but much easier to maintain.